# Implementing Complement Naive Bayes for continuous data?

Tags: gaussian, naive-bayes-algorithim

I'm looking to implement the Complement Naive Bayes algorithm for my continuous features. For the Gaussian technique I have calculated the normal distribution per feature x class, however what's the complement of this?